# iterator on a vector with templated class elements

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I use a templated class to define a 3D point (called `vec3<T>`), then I store some points in a vector. I used a `typdef` to define `vec3<double> as vec3d`;

Thus, I'm trying to get an iterator on my vector of `vector<vec3d>` and I have an error during the compilation process that I don't really understand. I think it is important to add that passing the `vector<vec3d>` by reference to a method of another class.

this is my code:

```
for(vector<vec3d>::iterator ite=neighboursList.begin(); ite!=neighboursList.end(); ++ite)
```

and this is the error message:

```
error: conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const vec3<double>*, std::vector<vec3<double>, std::allocator<vec3<double> > > >' to non-scalar type '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<vec3<double>*, std::vector<vec3<double>, std::allocator<vec3<double> > > >' requested
```

I would be really grateful if someone can spot what is wrong with what I am doing.

betaplus

Comment: You have vector of vectors of vec3ds? That's nested. How about flat storage with strided access?

Comment: I only have a vector of vec3ds and some "important" methods in my vec3d class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use const iterators:

```
for (std::vector<vec3d>::const_iterator ite=neighboursList.begin();
                     /*  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  /*    ite!=neighboursList.end(); ++ite)
{
    // ...
}
```

Or better, use `auto`:

```
for (auto ite = std::begin(neighbourList); ite != std::end(neighbourList); ++ite)
{
    // ...
}
```

Or better, don't use iterators:

```
for (auto const & neighbour : neighbourList)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the const iterator works. I was actually giving this vector as a const reference to a method of another class. That's why I needed to use a const_iterator.